# Can I write unit test in case exceptions are handled in Boundary classes?

Tags: unit-testing

So, I'm writing unit test for a function that add a new Patient record to db. Let's say I have some test cases: Add patient successfully, add patient with inputted age that is not numberic, add patient with only age inputted. I've done handling the blank textfields and non-numberic age in my boundary class, which means the errors are prevented right in the boundary class, and the adding function in patientDAO class always insert a valid new patient into db. So my question is, do I have to write unit test to test the last two test cases, and if I do, how can I do it? Because my adding function doesn't do the handling job.

Comment: I've read your question twice now, and am finding it very hard to understand. Could you, perhaps, include more details, perhaps some code?

Answer (score 0):

*I'm writing unit test for a function that **add a new Patient record to db***

Simple - your function responsibility is to save given patient data to the database.
You can write tests which check that given data successfully saved into database.

But, because your tests will save it to the real database, that mean it is not unit test anymore - you can call it integration tests.

Because responsibility of your function is only saving provided data, you don't need to write tests for input values validation. Your function will save anything you will provide as an argument.